# The usage of “into”

Tags: grammar

I am english learner and I am reading The Martian.

“Six days into what should be the greatest two months of my life, and it’s turned into a nightmare.”

What is the meaning of first “into”? The definitions provided by [Oxford Living  Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/into)  don’t seem to fit into the context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***[Into](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/into)*** is used to refer to the amount of time passed from the start of an action/event etc.

> (used to indicate a continuing extent in time or space):
>
> - lasted into the night; far into the distance.

(Dictionary.com)

In your sentence, it means that 6 days had passed since the beginning of the two months.

Comment: You'll also see phrases like "Six days in" or "Six days along" with the same meaning.